# If "Je t'aime" means "I love you", how do you say "I like you" in French while still addressing the other person as "tu"?

Tags: usage

There doesn't seem to be a way to indicate that one only *likes* a person with whom one is friends, rather than *loves* them.  Is there a way to indicate this while still referring to the friend as 'tu'?

Comment: Tutoiement has nothing to do with it; note that a similar difference exists between "je vous aime" and "je vous aime bien".

Comment: Voting to close as general reference (any bilingual dictionary will give you the answer).

Comment: So can someone clarify this, is there a distinction between I love you (romantic) and I like you (friends) that is in english also in French? If there is such a distinction (and it is not inferred just based on the context and the way it is said) what are the phrases used. Please also indicate where you are from (is this French, Canadian, ...)

Comment: I think it is a good question, as it is more a matter of cultural conventions not a strictly linguistic discussion.

Comment: Peut-être les Français ne savent pas aimer à moitié.

Comment: @Andre : Depends how you punctuate it (:P). If that's *“je t'aime, toi”* with an important comma (that is, if the emphasis is on *“aime”*), it can mean “ **you**, I like you” (or love), by opposition to someone that person would hate. If it's said with emphasis on *“toi”*, il can strongly suggest that person is in love with that other. If it's all said lightly, it can very well be a light-hearted “I like you” (“you're a cool person”). Bring context and tone to the rescue. If you want more opinions, open another question, I'd say it's worth it.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Je t'aime bien (literally: I love you much).

To change “love” to “like”, you need to modify it with an [adverb](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/aimer-lesson/).

Comment: We don't often use this one with people of the other sex like Pierre explains. It assumes a friendship relation but it's a little more subtle. We often use "Je t'aime bien" to imply we don't love ("je t'aime") the other person.

Comment: Indeed, "Je t'aime bien" is also a way of saying "but I'll nevere, ever, love you". To say "I love you", you'd rather use "Je ne te hais point."

Comment: @Joubarc What a citation! Indeed you can say that, but as a speaker of the language who currently lives in the country I would never use something like this orally.

Comment: Me neiher, but if the person you're trying to seduce knowns her/his classics, you may get bonus points. I guess I'm more on the "Tu ne me laisses pas indifférent." end of the spectrum than on the "Je te kiffe grave!!" one.

Comment: My understanding of the adverb in "je t'aime bien" might be something like "I like you well enough".

Comment: Peut-être « tu es très bonne » va bien, ou quelque adjectif d'autre qui spécifie une qualité appréciée ? Il faut c'est-à-dire spécifier pourquoi est-ce que je l'aime si bien…

Comment: @Evgeniy j'éviterais d'utiliser "tu es très bonne", cela peut être ambigu (bonne = "bien roulée" en argot)

Comment: Literally: I  love you well, not much.

Answer (score 70):

### Je t'apprécie

**Je t'aime bien** like Andrew Lewis suggests will work fine too, but it is safer to use **Je t'apprécie** with same sex persons.

In fact, *to like* is often translated as *apprécier* in French.

Comment: It can often be considered as a bit too formal in a spoken conversation though.

Comment: @Raphink: it's what I personnaly use. I use *Tu me plais* or *Je t'aime bien* with new girl friends ;) I'm not sure it's what the OP is asking for

Comment: I guess you mean girlfriends, rather than girl friends, or else you might get in trouble with your special one ;-)

Comment: @Raphink: yes exactly ;)

Comment: Chez nous on dit souvent "je t'apprécie beaucoup", mais de façon surprenante, on dit rarement "je t'apprécie" tout court. Ce n'est pas formel, et c'est rarement ambigü, exactement comme "I like you". Parfois, c'est aussi une façon de dire, en réponse à une avance, "I like you but sorry I don't love you".

Comment: why would it be safer with *same sex* person? are you making assumptions on the sexuality of the OP?

Comment: @njzk2 triggered.

Comment: This answer is 100% mistaken.

Answer (score 36):

"I like you" can be translated by:

> Je t'aime bien. ( I like you )
>
> Je te trouve sympa. ( I think you're nice )
>
> Je t'adore. (I like you a lot. (More used among girls))
>
> T'es sympa. ( You're nice )
>
> Je t'aime beaucoup. (I like you a lot, (and let's stay friend :P) )
>
> T'es un super pote. ( You're a super nice friend )
>
> On s'amuse bien ensemble. (We have fun together)

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to abbreviate "tu es" to "t'es"....I could be wrong?

Comment: In spoken French, "t'es" is as common as "you're" in English. (I am French.)

Comment: Wow, pro tip! Thanks. Never heard it before.

Comment: "On s'amuse bien ensemble" sound like what I would say to a sex friend.
This can be useful too.

Answer (score 29):

Generally, one would use:

> Je t'aime bien.

However, if you want to be more formal, then use rather the following:

> Je t'apprécie.

If you speak French with a foreign accent, then I suggest you use the second sentence as it sounds less naïve than the first one, which could be directly taken from the first lesson of any learning course.

Comment: You are right, the second is less naive, more serious in a certain way. We would rather say "je t'apprécie beaucoup", but "je t'apprécie" (especially with a foreign accent) would be perfectly understood and appreciated.

Answer (score 21):

More casually, **"Tu es sympa"**

Comment: Well, not that it is completely unrelated, but it would rather translate "You are nice/cool".

Answer (score 8):

You can even say "Je t'aime", but you need non-verbal communication like intonation and gestures, or some context or background with the other person that can avoid any misunderstanding.

Comment: Indeed. Something like "mais oui, je t'aime" express friendship. Maybe in a humorous way.

Answer (score 6):

Another good expression **Tu me plais**.

Comment: I think that's not the idea of the question. "Tu me plais" hides an attraction to the other person.

Comment: "Tu me plais" means I like you in a romantic way. I would never say that to a colleague or friend (or to anyone really).

Comment: Omg, sorry for misreading the question. You are absolutely right

Comment: I do not agree with the other comments, "tu me plais" can be used to espressed some kind of connivance as well ("tu me plais" meaning "I like you twisted way of thinking").

Comment: @Sylvain Peyronnet In that case we say something like "tu me plais bien, toi, tu as de bonnes idées". This is absolutely not ambiguous, you are right. Nevertheless the "tu me plais" (tout court) is actually more than ambiguous. It means "I find you attractive".

Comment: @Sylvain +1 I support you on this one. Though, I see many people disagreed so I suspect this usage can depend heavily on regions.

Comment: I think many people forgot to reread the very definition of the term ([here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plaire)). *Tu me plais* has WAY more meanings than just romance/love and is an excellent translation here.

Answer (score 5):

*I like you* can be translated to '*je te kiffe*' as a familiar language. Its origin is Arabic, see [kiffer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kiffer) on the Wiktionary.

Comment: A familiar language is a false friend here. familiar in English means: that one knows.

Answer (score 4):

Friends usually address themselves with "Je t'adore" or also you could make *périphrases* like "J’apprécie beaucoup être [en ta compagnie|avec toi]".

Comment: Really?  Friends would say to each other, 'I adore you'?

Comment: M'vy utilises-tu vraiment *je t'adore* si souvent? Moi je trouverais ça vraiment bizarre.

Comment: Apart from teenage girls saying that to their best friends, I can't imagine saying that to any of my friends...

Comment: @Pierre oui honnêtement. Après ça dépend du ton que tu utilises et de la situation, c'est sur.

Comment: "Je t'adore" is not really use between friends. "Je t'apprécie" and "Je t'aime bien" are the more common in my point of view.

Comment: @Raphink: the only French I know could use that is Helmut Fritz in a hyped nightclub in Paris ;) (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mNDYWhRSaw)

Comment: @Pierre: right...

Comment: Indeed, the tone is important when you use this expression! A way to tone it down is to use the form "Je t'adore, toi !" or "J't'adore trop" (even more familiar).

Comment: Yes, friends of opposite sex can say "je t'adore" in certain cases, and this doesn't mean "I find you attractive" nor "I love you". And this is not reserved to teenagers. But like @PhiLho said, the tone is very important in that case.

Comment: @Shlublu: I doubt it is common to understand "je t'adore" as "I find you attractive"

Comment: to address sb (as sth): to use a ptcl **name** or **title** for sb when you speak or write to them; *The judge should be addressed as 'your honour'*.

Answer (score 2):

As other said, you are dealing with an [untranslatable term](http://www.transeuropeennes.org/fr/articles/83). Languages support cultures, and different cultures build different social relations.

In French, there's no equivalent to *like*, just like there's no equivalent to *vous* in English. Of course one may use different language register in English, as well as one may express a whole shade of relational feelings in French. But it will be reflected in more complex constructions that you can't sum up in a one to one locution translation.

Using *tu* is already a way to express a more intimate relation. If you want to express that you like to spend time with a friend, you may say "je suis heureux qu’on soit ami(e)s, tu sais?". But as said, you will need to be more specific on what you want to express.

Edit by PamCam: this is off topic, but English *you* actually corresponds to French *vous* as can be seen from the verb it takes i.e. *you are* and not *you is*; therefore it is more appropriate to say that standard English does not have a form that corresponds to the French form *tu*.  Some dialects, though, allow expressions such as *you is* or *yous*, but that is a different matter altogether.

Addition by user 168676: I agree with PamCam and can mention additional information corroborating his/her contentions. In ancient times the English language has had the equivalent of a second person singular; the subject pronoun was "thou" in which we find the t of "tu" in french and a phonetically close sound in the German "du" which is modern German "tu"; the second person of the verb "to be" was "art" in which again we find the t of the second person singular of the German "sein" which is "bist" (verb "to be" in German); the English language is a Germanic language, that being due to the early migrations towards Britain of a germanic people known as the Angles. It might be added that the second person singular has persisted in English poetry for a long time and that it is found in some English dialects still spoken in England; we get a substantial exposure to one of those dialects in the contemporary (and once controversial) literary work of D.H. Lawrence, Lady Chatterley's lover.

Comment: This is completely inaccurate. Languages reproduce equivalent **meanings** not equivalent words. And the trick is knowing when to use aimer/aimer bien and like/love in English. It should not be explained away by saying something exists. The concept of love and friendship exist in both French and Anglo cultures.

Comment: Of course the broad concept of love exists in French and Anglo culture. And in both you can find advanced concept like [philia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philia) and [agape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agape) borrowed from  Ancient Greek. But that is not the point here. The question was more like "is there a direct (obvious) equivalent expressions that transpose in French 'I love you' vs ’I like you.'" The closest thing I could come with would be "Je t’apprécie", keeping the constraint of a form of "subject object verb".

Comment: I like you, je t'aime bien; I love you, je t'aime.

Comment: Well, sure it might work, just like `j’te kiffe` in an other register. 

Comment: It is not that it might work. These are basically "canonical" translations. No one disputes them.

Comment: To me, context is evrything. But feel free to translate everything regardless of context with binld faith for the sacrosanct canonical practices. 

Answer (score 0):

"Je t'aime bien" est ce qui se rapproche de le plus de "I like you".

Comment: Right, exactly.

Answer (score -2):

Whether addressing the other person as "tu" or as "vous", "I like you" can always be rendered without ambiguity by **"J'ai de l'amitié pour toi."** and **"J'ai de l'amitié pour vous.**".

Comment: That should restaure  Andrew Vit's confidence (*) in the fact that the French do know how to "half-love" or shall we say "how to like". 

( see witty comment in the question if it's been missed)

Comment: I cannot understand the negative  vote.

Comment: @dimitris I can't either, but voting rules the world!

Comment: @dimitris Is that vote yours? It must be. Thanks!