# “Échapper” or “s'échapper”, which is correct in this sentence?

Tags: prépositions, verbes, verbes-pronominaux

I have a two part question:
1) My sentence is

> I escape the lion.

Do I say

> Je èchappe le lion

or

> Je s'echapper du lion

or neither?

2) I see other verbs that are otherwise identical but one will have a *s'* before them. My grammar book does not explain what the purpose of the *s'* is. Could someone explain this to me or direct me to a resource online?

Comment: A quick search for `s' before verb french` on Google gives an appropriate answer for (2).

Comment: Thank you. I tried googling it but I did not think to try that phrase. It turned up many useful guides!

Comment: This [question & answers](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/4460/358) about reflexive verbs might help you.

Comment: You should **never** use an infinitive after a subject ! (Je s'echapper) Use "s'échapper" only when it's alone, it's what this form is about, never after a subject.

Answer (score 9):

A correct answer with "échapper" is:

> J'échappe au lion.

Together with a person/object, you says "j'échappe à/au".

The form "je m'échappe du/de" is used together with a location:

> Je m'échappe de la prison.
>
> Je m'échappe du pays.

Last but not least, you can also use the verb "fuir", which is used the same way with locations or persons:

> Je fuis le lion.
>
> Je fuis la prison.

For your second question, see:
https://french.stackexchange.com/a/4594/11668