# La voix passive interchangeable avec le verbe pronominal ?

Tags: grammaire, verbes-pronominaux, passif

J'appuie ce qui suit sur *Advanced French Grammar*, p. 15, par V. Mazet et [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4460/can-we-use-the-pronoun-se-with-every-verb/4464).

> In many cases, and especially when the "agent" is expressed, French tries to avoid the passive ... In some cases, a singular or plural pronominal (reflexive) form with **se** is used (Although promonomial verbs themselves are never used in the passive).

Est-il toujours possible d'alterner entre la voix passive et l'utilisation d'un verbe pronominal ? Les deux sont-ils identiques ou y a-t-il une raison de choisir l'un ou l'autre ?

Voici 4 exemples :

1. De Georges Buffon :

   > On a laissé pendant ce temps l'entrée du creuset ouverte, et celle de la tuyère bien bouchée, pour empêcher le feu de se communiquer aux soufflets. La première impression de la grande chaleur produite par le long séjour des braises ardents et par cette première combustion du charbon, **s'est marquée** par une petite fente qui **s'est faite** dans la pierre du fond à l'entrée du creuset, et par une autre fente qui **s'est faite** dans la pierre de la tympe.
2. De Honoré de Balzac :

   > Ce mot : « – Vois donc un peu si monsieur Deschars se permet jamais. . . » est une épée de Damoclès, ou ce qui est pis, une épingle ; et votre amour-propre est la pelote où votre femme la fourre continuellement, la retire et la refourre, sous une foule de prétextes inattendus et variés, en se servant d’ailleurs des termes d’amitié les plus câlins ou avec des façons assez gentilles.
   >
   > Adolphe, taonné jusqu’à se voir tatoué de piqûres, finit par faire ce qui **se fait** en bonne police, en gouvernement, en stratégie.
3. De Victor Duruy :

   > Les trente-deux quai tiers représentent les armoiries des trente-deux chanoines nobles de Lyon. Le premier quartier est de gueules ou rouge au sautoir engrèlé d'urgent. La 
   >   couleur de gueules ou rouge **se marque** en gravure par des traits perpendiculaires; 
   >   l'argent, en laissant le fond bout uni sans points et sans hachures...
4. De la part de *Poésies fugitives, Volume 2* de Charles de Lonchamps :

   > La vie humaine, en raccourci,
   >   Est un mât de cocagne aussi.
   >   Au pied du mât l'enfant succombe;
   >   D'un peu plus haut l'adulte tombe ;
   >   L'âge mûr **se hisse** aux trois quarts;
   >   et quelques obstinés viellards
   >   vont ceindre, au haut de la colonne,
   >   un fatal cyprès pour couronne.

Dans le texte de Buffon, rien ne change si on remplace *s'est marquée* par *a été marquée*, et *s'est faite* par *a été faite* ?

De même, dans les autres textes, peut-on remplacer *se fait* par *est fait(e)*, *se marque* par *est marquée* ou *se hisse* par *est hissé* ?

Comment: Je pense que non, utiliser un verbe pronominal dans ces phrases est un style littéraire qui ne passerait pas toujours en français contemporain courant, et il y a des cas où seul le passif marche. Il faudrait que j'y réfléchisse plus pour écrire une vraie réponse.

Comment: Après mon OP, j'ai biffé les citations sans rapport (de de Quélen et Hugo) et enchâssé deux autres citations que j'espère sont pertinentes.

Comment: @Gilles: Merci de votre petite info. N'hésitez pas à prendre votre temps !

Answer (score 3):

D'une part, si les verbes pronominaux expriment parfois un sens passif, ce n'est pas le cas de tous.  Grevisse les classe en réfléchis (*se laver*), réciproques (*se regarder*), subjectifs (*se douter*, les verbes essentiellement pronominaux comme *s'abstenir* en font partie) et passifs (*s'appeler*).  Seuls les derniers ont un sens passif.

D'autre part il me semble qu'il y a souvent une nuance entre l'usage de la voix passive et celle d'une construction pronominale passive.

> Ce livre se lit en une soirée.

Donne une caractéristique du livre.

> Ce livre est lu en une soirée.

Ne me semble absolument pas naturel hors de tout contexte, ce que la phrase précédente est.  Et les contextes qui rendent la phrase possible, font que la phrase se réfère à un événement précis.  Pour construire un équivalent à la première phrase en utilisant la voix passive, il faut quelque chose comme

> Ce livre peut être lu en une soirée.

---

Dans le cas des exemples:

- Chez Buffon, *impression* est utilisé avec un sens plutôt vieilli d'action ou d'influence.  Et je ne suis pas sûr que *se marquer* n'est pas aussi utilisé avec un sens inusité de nos jours car si je comprends le sens général de la phrase, j'ai du mal avec le sens précis de *marquer* ici.  Je ne suis pas sûr du sens passif de la phrase car c'est bien l'action de la chaleur qui crée la fente.
- Chez Buffon, les *se faire* sont clairement passifs et faire est un verbe trop imprécis pour y discerner des nuances.
- Chez Hyacinthe-Louis de Quélen, le *s'est marquée* ne me semble absolument pas passif.  (*Le cardinal s'est marqué une place auprès de deux grand évêques.*)
- Chez Victor Hugo, le sens ne me semble pas passif (*L'ingratitude fait une étude de l'oubli des bienfaits.*)
- Chez Honoré de Balzac, le *se faire* me semble aussi passif.